# EF 7 Running All Migration upon Update-Database

Tags: database, entity-framework

All migrations are being run when I use Update-Database from within the PMC.

My DB migration history is:

[image]

The migration list is:
PM> Get-Migration
Build started...
Build succeeded.
[10:12:19 INF] Starting Up
[10:12:19 INF] Create and configure application

id                                         name                        safeName                    applied

---

20230821114457_Initial Create              Initial Create              Initial Create                False
20230821125833_Company Remove Subscriber   Company Remove Subscriber   Company Remove Subscriber     False
20230821165356_Catch Changes               Catch Changes               Catch Changes                 False
20230822141934_Change C1099 Id Company Ref Change C1099 Id Company Ref Change C1099 Id Company Ref   False
20230822155929_Company_AddressId_Null      Company_AddressId_Null      Company_AddressId_Null        False

Comment: _"All migrations are being run "_ - how do you determine that? Do you have exceptions stating that some object already exists in the database?

Comment: Upon Updata-Database an exception for Create table Address from the Initial Create is thrown.

Comment: Do you have a [mre]? Is there any chance that migration history table name was changed?

Comment: No minimal reproducible example.  The migration history table name was not changed. If you delete the DB then all migration run.

Answer (score 0):

I have several appsettings.{environment}.json, Production, Development, and others within my application.

For some reason, if you do an update database without using -connection, it uses the connection string in the Production environment and not the development one.

By providing the -connect to the update, it references the correct db.